# Cannot install, screens keep flashing never load ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, nvidia, grub2, flash

I'm trying to install ubuntu in an old computer (pentium4, 1.5mhz, 512mb ram).
After installing from a cd, the screen started to flash and ubuntu never loaded. I read that Nvidia's graphics card driver is not easy to install, so I decided to swap it out for an old Hercules graphic card, and install again. The same thing happened, it never loaded and it kept flashing and trying to load ubuntu.

### Then I tried :

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

but I couldn't write or exit.

Starting it holding shift key, and with E adding "nomodeset" after "quiet splash", and it load it but with no icon in the side not nor top menu, just empty.

I don't know how to continue. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry DracNoc didnt answer before,
now i have more ram 850mb, i also found anothe graphiccard Hercules 3d prophet II MX(32mb).
i was reading that Lubuntu use LXDE and not Unity. do u think Lubuntu and Hercules will have any problem with the graphiccard?
thanks for help.
P

Comment: Pablo - you appear to have two accounts.  Please click the contact-us link at the bottom of the page and request your accounts are merged.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what nVidia card you're trying to use, it would be good to know as there are different drivers for different types of card.

Also, 512Mb/RAM is a little low, Xubuntu might be a better choice. I have a gut feeling that the 3D requirements for the Unity desktop might be playing merry havoc with your graphics output.

Comment: the nvidia video card is:
ASUS GeForce 2 MX 400 (V7100 / DC / 32M / P / U Deluxe Combo) AGP 32 Мб
NVIDIA GeForce2 MX
32 MB / 32 MB (max) - SDRAM
I there a way to find the ubuntu driver for this?
Do you think i will have the same problem with Xubuntu?

Comment: Wow, that's a really old card. I know that the nVidia 96.x driver runs this card, but it's no longer available as a standard driver. You can get it directly from nVidia.com, but in the install is not as easy. It's possible, but this is not going to be an easy answer. The same problem will apply to Xubuntu or any other K/L/X/Ubuntu system. You may want to find something like an nVidia 6200/6250 card. That will run on the 173.x driver which is available.